# rails rendering two bodys on each page, current and previous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure what exactly is the issue so the best I could do is launch the page for someone to look at.

https://campadventureland.herokuapp.com/

The git repository is:

https://github.com/rickymm3/campadventurelandnew

When I open the initial load, everything is fine. When i click on a link (brand home link, or FAQ (under about) - it loads the page contents twice.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**
 - It's a `turbolinks` effect, when it fires event twice

**Solution**
 - Don't use it in your project. Remove turbolinks from Gemfile, data-attributes from head section and requirement from application.js

**More info**

There're many issues about it, I think, you may start from this

- [Turbolinks double loaded pages](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/403)

And this

- [How Turbolinks works](https://www.mskog.com/posts/instant-page-loads-with-turbolinks-and-prefetch/)

> Turbolinks speeds up your site by intercepting any requests made from
>   clicking on links for example. Instead of letting the browser do a
>   full page load and changing the page it instead loads the content with
>   AJAX and replaces the body of the page with the body of the new page.
>   This means that the browser does not have to interpret any CSS or JS
>   assets from the new page. The speed improvement from doing this can be
>   huge if you have big assets like a lot of Javascript. Because of how
>   Turbolinks works there are some issues and gotchas however. For
>   example you cannot use the standard $(document).ready for pages loaded
>   by Turbolinks. You have to use the events coming from Turbolinks
>   instead. **There are also issues with event handlers binding twice if
>   you are not careful.** Nonetheless, Turbolinks can be a huge improvement
>   for many applications.